# Ruby: replace a multi-line text inside a document with another text

Tags: ruby, string, replace, newline

I have the following document:

```
Some code...
Some more code...

@NiceFunction
    Function content
    More function content
@End

Even more code...
```

Now I read this into a string using Ruby and want to replace everything between `@NiceFunction` and `@End` with something different.

I tried `string.gsub! /@NiceFunction(.*)@End/, "some other function content"` but this doesn't seem to work with line breaks.

I also tried `string.gsub! /@NiceFunction([.\n]*)@End/, "some other function content"`, with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions, in ruby, disable multi-line mode matching by default. This means the wildcard `.` character does not match new-lines.

You can [enable this](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) with the `/m` modifier:

```
/@NiceFunction(.*)@End/m
```

---

This attempt you made also seems reasonable:

```
/@NiceFunction([.\n]*)@End/
```

...But unfortunately *when inside a character set*, `.` loses its special meaning - so this pattern is actually just looking for repeats of the two characters `"."` and `"\n"`, and would not match anything else.

There is, however, a similar approach you could have taken to match "any character, including newline", without enabling multiline mode. You can do something like this:

```
/@NiceFunction([\s\S]*)@End/
```

...Which is saying to match "any whitespace, or non-whitespace". In other words, absolutely anything.

The above approach would technically work for any pairing of negated groups - e.g. `[\d\D]`, or `[\w\W]`, or `[\h\H]`, ... but it's somewhat of an unofficial standard to use `[\s\S]` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [rubular](https://rubular.com/) for testing regular expressions. Currently you need 'm' modificator I think

```
string.gsub! /@NiceFunction(.*)@End/m, "some other function content"
```